# How to write file to nfs in NestJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, nfs

I am trying to write a file to NFS in my nestjs project. Is it possible to do that? It is barely to find a source talking about it.

Comment: Ask your question in a better way will help you get better feedback. For instance; mention what NFS stands for?

Comment: Can you write a file to NFS without nestjs?

Comment: Are you talking about the Network File System(NFS) of AWS? Please provide some scenarios, what you've tried and what didn't work so that contributers can better understand you question?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to write a file to our private NFS (not cloud) in NestJS, it is possible to do that?